# How has the author obtained Riemann-Stieltjes sum of $g$ wrt $f$ as $f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} f(x_i) [g(y_k) - g(y_{k-1})]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

In the book of *The elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle, at page 232, it is given that

> [...]
>
> Let $J = [a,b]$, and $P$ be a partition of $J$. Define $$S(P; f,
>  g) = \sum_{k=1}^n g(e_k) [f(x_k)- f(x_{k-1})],$$ where $x_{k-1} \leq
>  e_k \leq x_k$, and $x_i$s are the end points of $P$. Let $Q= (y_0,
>  y_1, ..., y_{2n})$ be partition of $J$ obtained by using both $e_k$
>   and $x_k$ as partition points; hence $x_{2k} = x_k$ and $y_{2k-1} =
>  e_k$. Add and substract the terms $f(x_{2k}) g(x_{2k})$, $k=0,...,n$
>   to $S(P; f, g)$, and rearrange to obtaion $$S(P; g, f) = f(b)g(b) -
>  f(a)g(a) - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} f(x_i) [g(y_k) - g(y_{k-1})],$$ [...]
>
> we get  $$\int_a^b f dg + \int_a^b gdf = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a)$$

My question is that how the author did obtain
$$f(b)g(b) -
 f(a)g(a) - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} f(x_i) [g(y_k) - g(y_{k-1})]$$ from adding the terms $f(x_{2k}) g(x_{2k})$, $k=0,...,n$ to $$\sum_{k=1}^n g(e_k) [f(x_k)- f(x_{k-1})].$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a telescoping sum, we have

$$f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n[f(x_k)g(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})g(x_{k-1})] \\ = \sum_{k=1}^ng(x_k)f(x_k) - \sum_{k=1}^ng(x_{k-1})f(x_{k-1}). $$

Hence,

$$\tag{1}S(P;f,g) - \left[f(b)g(b) - f(a) g(a) \right] \\= \sum_{k=1}^n g(e_k)[f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}) - \sum_{k=1}^ng(x_k)f(x_k) + \sum_{k=1}^ng(x_{k-1})f(x_{k-1}) \\ =  -\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_{k-1})[g(e_k) - g(x_{k-1})] +  \sum_{k=1}^nf(x_{k})[g(x_k) - g(e_{k})] \right) $$

Subsituting with $x_k = y_{2k}$, $x_{k-1} = y_{2k-2}$ and  $e_k = y_{2k-1}$ in the last line of (1) we obtain

$$\tag{2}S(P;f,g) - \left[f(b)g(b) - f(a) g(a) \right] \\=-\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(y_{2k-2})[g(y_{2k-1}) - g(y_{2k-2})] +  \sum_{k=1}^nf(y_{2k})[g(y_{2k}) - g(y_{2k-1})] \right)$$

Define special "intermediate points" $\xi_{2k-1} = y_{2k-2}$ and $\xi_{2k} = y_{2k}$. Substituting into (2) we obtain

$$\tag{3}S(P;f,g) - \left[f(b)g(b) - f(a) g(a) \right] \\=-\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(\xi_{2k-1})[g(y_{2k-1}) - g(y_{2k-2})] +  \sum_{k=1}^nf(\xi_{2k})[g(y_{2k}) - g(y_{2k-1})] \right)$$

Taking $j = 2k$, equation (3) is equivalent to

$$S(P;f,g) = f(b)g(b) - f(a) g(a)    -\sum_{j=1}^{2n} f(\xi_j)[g(y_j) - g(y_{j-1})]$$

The sum on the RHS is a Riemann-Stieltjes sum of $f$ with respect to $g$ over $[a,b]$.

Note that Bartle has been a little vague in using the notation $x_i$ where I use $\xi_j$, defined precisely above.

Comment: Yeah, Bartle does that a lot in his book. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73072/room-for-onurcanbektas-and-rrl

Comment: @onurcanbektas: You're welcome.  I just saw your message in chat about a book recommendation.  You ask good questions - shows you are really trying to understand this material at a deeper level.  Like you I would read books like Bartle and try to dissect the proofs and fill in the missing steps.  As to recommendations --

Comment: There is no one good analysis book..  Individually you get an incomplete picture and some cover some topics better than others. Obviously Rudin,, Royden,, Aposto,, Bartle are standard.  Apostol covers integration on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but to get better insight you can look at Spivak (Calculus on Manifolds) and Munkres (Analysis on Manifolds).  These are better than Zorich in many respects.

Comment: Most general analysis books focus on basic theorems without providing many examples of application -- so you don't get much practice in learning techniques and how to apply the results.  For example, you might learn Fubini's theorem, but how would you prove you can switch the order for $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x \, dx\,dy$. It is not absolutely integrable.  I would look at the old books like Whitakker and Watson and Titchmarsh and also A Second Course in Mathematical Analysis by Burkill and Burkill.

Comment: I also would like to use the Spivak's book, but I'm just learning Topology (by myself), and I'm doing double major on mathematics actually, so I did not took a rigorous calculus course in my frehman year (only the thing that I have myself), so I specifically wanted to study a book that is rigorous in its  theory, but not going to much general (for example calculus on manifolds). I mean if I had done that, it would be like studying triple/triple integrals without even knowing what does an integral in one dimension mean.

Comment: I will definetely check out the books that you have mentioned, thanks a lot :)